# Select Case is not working with Order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

I was using a simple sql query and getting an ordered list, but when I changed some of the values in the  column I'm sorting by, those rows were no longer being sorted correctly.

```
select distinct u.Email, 
  case 
    when l.region_id is null then 'EU' 
    else l.region_id 
  end 
  as Location 
from TB_User u 
left join cat..location l on l.location=u.Location 
where u.Username in (....)
order by l.region_id
```

I have about 5 rows that returned null for their region_id so they would be at the top of the result set. When I added the case and replaced their value, they still remain at the top. Is there anyway to make these rows sort according to their given value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` also in the `ORDER BY`. But in this case it seems that you instead want to order by the column which uses the `CASE`.

```
ORDER BY Location
```

If you instead want the null-regions at the bottom:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN l.region_id is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC,  
         Location  ASC
```

If your rdbms doesn't support this (like SQL-Server does) you have to repeat it:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN l.region_id IS NULL THEN 'EU' ELSE l.region_id END ASC
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: what exactly do you mean by this? You _can_ use the alias in the `Order By` (at least in SQL-Server).

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right - all major RDBMSs support aliased fields in `ORDER BY`. It's the `WHERE` condition where using `Location` would be problematic, but that's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You just order by the column value, which is null.
If you want to order by the case statement, just copy it in the order by clause:

```
order by   
  case 
    when l.region_id is null then 'EU' 
    else l.region_id end
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using SQL**, try within the `SELECT` statement, use:

```
ISNULL(l.region_id, 'EU') AS Location
```

and then

```
ORDER BY 2
```

This will make your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.Email, ISNULL(l.region_id, 'EU') AS Location 
FROM TB_User u 
LEFT JOIN cat..location l ON l.location=u.Location 
WHERE u.Username in (....)
ORDER BY 2
```